# Iteration in a single line

Tags: python

I have some code of the form:

```
for i in range(nIterations):
    y = f(y)
```

Where `f` is a function defined elsewhere. hopefully the idea of that code is that after it's run `y` will have had  `f` applied to it `nIterations` times.

Is there a way in python to write this in a single line?

Comment: why would you want to write this in a single line?

Comment: This could be useful if you're doing interactive stuff at the console. One-liners tend to be easier to copy-paste in the python console.

Comment: Otherwise, it just seems like a bad idea.

Comment: It's certainly a bad idea if anyone else ever wants to read the code. however this is just an exercise in python's ability to do ridiculous one liners simply because most things can be a list comprehension.
Just wanted to know if it could be done.

Comment: @VolatileStorm: that's not the job for list comprehension, because they're designed to iterate over each element of an iterable, you're not using iterable within loop at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

like this?

```
for i in range(nIterations): y = f(y)
```

A for loop with one command can be written as a single line.

**EDIT**

Or maybe slightly cleaner:

```
for _ in xrange(nIterations): y = f(y)
```

Since you don't want to have a something that can be split into two separate statements (i think), here's another one:

```
reduce(lambda y, _: f(y), xrange(nIterations), initValue)
```

Still, I would recommend to **just use your original code**, which is much more intuitive and readable. Also note what [Guido van Rossum](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=211200) has to say on loops versus `repeat`.
Note by the way that (in python 2.x) `xrange` is more efficient than `range` for large nIterations as it returns an actual iterator and not an allocated list.

Comment: +1 - I think that there is a pythonesque way to do what the OP wants though.

Comment: haha. No. All you've done is removed the return, in my mind it's still "there", and two separate lines. I'm just doing this as an exercise in ridiculousness, haha, and wondering if there's a way that it could be done.

Comment: Yes, I've only removed your return. Now it's a single line. What more do you want ;)

Comment: Wasn't python set to lose the `reduce` function? Or am I wholly behind the times here?

Comment: @Daniel May, reduce is still available in Python3, but has been moved to the functools module. See http://diveintopython3.org/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#reduce

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I pretty much understand how that's gonna work apart from the definition of the lambda function.

lambda y, _: f(y)

Why is there the ", _"? What purpose does that serve?

Comment: The `_` is just a placeholder for a temporary variable you won't use later. If you read this code, it's immediately clear you're not really interested in that variable, but you need to include it anyway to make the code work.

Answer (score 3):

So like this you mean?

```
for i in range(nIterations): y = f(y)
```

While this might seem nice and pretty, I'd argue (as has been done in the comments below your post) that this **doesn't** improve readability, and is best off left as 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Just stick it all on one line like this: `for i in range(nIterations): y = f(y)`

The decision to have code on one line or multiple has been an argument for years - there is no performance increase - just lay it out how you like it and how **you** can read it best.

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks context, but this could be rewritten using `map` function or list comprehension (both one-liners)

Comment: how could it be rewritten using list comprehensions? That's kinda what I'm looking for.

Comment: It could be rewritten with `reduce`, but not with `map` or a list comprehension.

Comment: You're right, guys - missed the point. I'd better read it more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly one line, but once you define the power operation for functions:

```
def f_pow(f, n):
  if n == 1:
    return f
  else:
    return lambda x: f_pow(f, n-1)(f(x))
```

you can write this:

```
f_pow(f, nIterations)(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

`reduce(lambda y,_: f(y),xrange(niterations),y)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is probably a very weird an incomprehensible use of the `reduce` function, so for real code I'd stick with what you have. But just for the fun of it, here goes:

```
reduce(lambda a, b: f(a), range(nIterations), y)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make `y` mutable, then you can use list comprehension. But this isn't something I'd use in real code, unless **really** necessary.

```
def f(y):
    y[0] += 5

y = [0]
[f(y) for _ in xrange(10)]
print y[0] # => 50
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'd suggest you keep the original code snippet as it is much clearer, you can accomplish this with a single line of code using the reduce function:

```
reduce(lambda a,b: f(a), xrange(nIterations), y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create such snippets using semicolons **;** if you need to execute more than one instruction inside the loop, here is an example:

```
for i in xrange(nIterations): x=f(i); y=f(x); z=f(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

`y=[f(y) for i in range(niteration)]`

hope that helps ;)